# Java: Need to extract a number from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string containing a number. Something like `"Incident #492 -  The Title Description"`.
I need to extract the number from this string.
Tried

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");  
Matcher m = p.matcher(theString);  
String substring =m.group();
```

By getting an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

What am I doing wrong?
What is the correct expression?
I'm sorry for such a simple question, but I searched a lot and still not found how to do this (maybe because it's too late here...)

Comment: Can you assert that there will not be other numbers in the String?

Comment: Yes, in my case there is only one, single number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you need to call `find()` on the matcher before accessing `group`s:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(theString);  
while (m.find()) {
    String substring =m.group();
    System.out.println(substring);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/pelFGC)

Comment: Or `matches()` if theString is not allowed extraneous characters.

Comment: @Andreas That's right. OP's string allows other characters, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong here:

- The pattern you're using is not the most ideal for your scenario, it's only checking if a string *only* contains numbers.  Also, since it doesn't contain a group expression, a call to `group()` [is equivalent to calling `group(0)`, which returns the entire string.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int))
- You need to be *certain* that the matcher has a match before you go calling a group.

Let's start with the regex.  Here's what it looks like now.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yy_zxX9VsVFifxn8)

That will ***only*** ever match a string that contains all numbers in it.  What you care about is *specifically* the number in that string, so you want an expression that:

- Doesn't care about what's in front of it
- Doesn't care about what's after it
- Only matches on one occurrence of numbers, and captures it in a group

To that, you'd use this expression:

```
.*?(\\d+).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wM5ePVXF9CndLfqt)

The last part is to ensure that the matcher can find a match, and that it gets the correct group.  That's accomplished by this:

```
if (m.matches()) {
    String substring = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(substring);
}
```

All together now:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\d+).*");
final String theString = "Incident #492 -  The Title Description";
Matcher m = p.matcher(theString);
if (m.matches()) {
    String substring = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(substring);
}
```

Comment: The pattern OP is using is 100% correct, as long as you are not trying to use `matches()` on it. He does not need the stuff in front or behind the `\\d+` part, and he does not need groups beyond the default group zero, unless he wishes to capture other parts of the string.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight:  I'll rephrase it then - it's not the most ideal regex to use, then.  It will work so long as you're using `find`, but when I author regexes, I like it to be clear that it's going to match *specific* things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke one of the `Matcher` methods, like `find`, `matches` or `lookingAt` to actually run the match.